# Java Generic Type for Wildcard extends allow to add only null

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors, wildcard, extends

I am using the below code and tryin to add CHild object is the list:

```
List<? extends Parent> list =  new ArrayList<Child>();
 list.add(new Child()); //error: The method add(capture#1-of ? extends Parent) in the type        List<capture#1-of ? extends Parent> is not applicable for the arguments (Child)

class Parent{
}
class Child extends Parent{
}
```

I want to know why compiler throws error here?

Comment: If you want to solve, replace `List<? extends Parent>` to `List<Parent>`. If you want to understand google for covariance and contravariance.

Comment: Why do you declare the type of `list` as `List<? extends Parent>` if you don’t know what it means? If you create a `ArrayList<Child>` why don’t you keep it as `List<Child>`?

Comment: *Why do you declare the type of list as List<? extends Parent> if you don’t know what it means?* , @Holger, thats how people learn, by doing things :)

Comment: @sanbhat: no, that’s the perfect counter-example. This user learned by reading your explanation and possibly by reading the linked article. Just reading the linked article in the first place would have caused the same effect. In a shorter time. That’s what tutorials are for.

Comment: stackoverflow.com is a Q&A site, not a "Why does the asker ask that question" discussion forum...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go through the [Generic Guidelines](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcardGuidelines.html) stated by Oracle docs, these kind of list declarations are tend to be **read-only** (no write operations can be performed)

Quoted from the page

> A list defined by `List<? extends ...>` can be informally thought of as
>   read-only, but that is not a strict guarantee.

As per your example, let us assume `Child2` and `Child3` `extends Parent`, then

`List<? extends Parent>` list can be a list of any of these subclasses. Adding a specific subclass element can cause runtime error, thus compiler complains in advance

Answer (score 0):

As per your example, i am able to figure out that **List of Parent** and **List of Child** are not subtype  of each other even though Child is subtype of Parent, in a similar way like **List of Number** and **List of Integer** are not subtype of either. If it was possible, you could have added not an Integer to **List of Number** which lead to type safety voilation.

For your requirement you can do something like below mentioned

```
  List<Number> numberList = new ArrayList<Number>();

    List<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Double> doubleList = new ArrayList<Double>();
    List<Float> floatList = new ArrayList<Float>();

    numberList.addAll(integerList);
    numberList.addAll(doubleList);
    numberList.addAll(floatList);
```

Here check for arguments to addAll() method.